# Controller with scope variable not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[From Documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/concepts)

> The syntax `InvoiceController as invoice` tells Angular to instantiate
>   the controller and save it in the variable invoice in the current
>   scope.
>
> We also changed all expressions in the page to read and write
>   variables within that controller instance by prefixing them with
>   `invoice`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
    <p>Hello {{invoice.name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('InvoiceController', function() {
  this.name = 'World';
});
```

But it is not working as mentioned in the document. I just moved the inline scripts to external file.

[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQU34HdbArrHQMdSQzmJ?p=preview)

Also why it is not working if i pass `$scope` to the controller function

```
app.controller('InvoiceController', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set the ng-app

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
<!-- REST OF HTML -->
</html>
```

Comment: Any idea, why it is not working if I pass `$scope` to the controller?

Comment: You have to change the html to {{name}}. It will read from scope, not the controller.

Comment: Then what is the use of `ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice"`?

Comment: This article will answer your question:
http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/